# I've a mistake BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range

Tags: python, mysql

I use MySql. When I call the same procedure using sql and python I get different responses:
In MySql it works well but when I call it in python I get another response

```
(1690, "BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`shop`.`t`.`lvl` - `shop`.`tree`.`lvl`)'")
```

Procedure:

```
    delimiter $$
CREATE procedure daily_users (us_id bigint) 
BEGIN 
    set @us_id = us_id;
     set @u_lvl = (select lvl from users where user_id = @us_id);
     set @children_first_lvl = (select count(1)
            from tree t
            join users u   
                on t.user_id = u.user_id
            join (select * from tree where user_id = @us_id) sub
                on (sub.lft < t.lft and sub.rgt > t.rgt) 
            where (t.lvl - sub.lvl) = 1 and u.lvl > 0);
    set @all_children = (select count(1)
            from tree t
            join users u   
                on t.user_id = u.user_id
            join (select * from tree where user_id = @us_id ) sub
                on (sub.lft < t.lft and sub.rgt > t.rgt) 
                where (t.lvl - sub.lvl) <= (select lvl from users where user_id = @us_id) 
            and u.lvl > 0);
    set @new_first_lvl = (select count(1)
            from tree t
            join users u   
                on t.user_id = u.user_id
            join (select * from tree where user_id = @us_id ) sub
                on (sub.lft < t.lft and sub.rgt > t.rgt) where u.when_joined = date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), '%y-%m-%d' ));
    set @earned_yesterday = (select ifnull(sum(value_of_payment),0) from outcomming_payments 
                where date_format(time_of_act, '%y-%m-%d') = date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), '%y-%m-%d') 
                and user_id = @us_id
                and (is_it_end = 1 and is_it_success = 1));
    set @erned_all = (select ifnull(sum(value_of_payment),0) from outcomming_payments 
                where user_id = @us_id 
                and (is_it_end = 1 and is_it_success = 1));
    set @balance = (select balance from users where user_id = @us_id );
    set @children_nex_lvl = (select count(1)
            from tree t
            join users u   
                on t.user_id = u.user_id
            join (select * from tree where user_id = @us_id  ) sub
                on (sub.lft < t.lft and sub.rgt > t.rgt) 
            where (t.lvl - sub.lvl) = (select lvl from users where user_id = @us_id ) + 1 );
            
     insert into daily_response(user_id, user_lvl, children_first_lvl, all_children, new_first_lvl, earned_yesterday, erned_all, balance, children_nex_lvl)
                        value (@us_id , @u_lvl, @children_first_lvl, @all_children, @new_first_lvl, @earned_yesterday, @erned_all, @balance, @children_nex_lvl);
end;$$
delimiter
```

How I call that in python:

```
def users_response_db(self,data):
    self.cur.execute(f"call daily_users('{data}')")
    self.conn.commit()
    my_execute = f""";
                    select * from daily_response
                    where user_id = '{data}' 
                    order by id_daily desc
                    limit 1;"""
    self.cur.execute(my_execute)
    return self.cur.fetchone()
```

I already tried to use **SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';**

Comment: Maybe the substraction result is negative simply?

Comment: There is no way to be true cause it works in sql

Comment: Replace the problematic expression with ```.. ((@tmp1 := `shop`.`t`.`lvl`) - (@tmp2 := `shop`.`tree`.`lvl`)) ..``` and, after query fails, look at `SELECT @tmp1, @tmp2;`.

Comment: Yeah, nice advice but i solved that by another way. Thank you

Comment: And what was the source of your problem?

Comment: I just published an answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in this part of code

```
(select * from tree where user_id = @us_id )
```

I don't need to use all from this subtable.
I solved that when I replaced `*` with required columns. In my solution it looks like that:

```
(select lft,rgt,lvl from tree where user_id = @us_id )
```